# How to specify gems to Capistrano per deployment config?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

We have a Ruby on Rails project that we're deploying to two servers using Capistrano. One server will use MySQL, the other will use PostgreSQL. So they will need the `mysql` and `pg` gems respectively. We don't want to install both gems on both machines.

Ideally it would be nice to say in the deployment configuration for each server that we would like to include this gem for this deployment and that gem for that deployment.

We currently have two branches of the code, each with a different `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock`. It works but it's ugly.

Any ideas that would allow us to specify per-configuration Gems, or provide on the command-line for `cap deploy`?

Comment: that's... a really odd request, can I ask why you have the app running on two different dbs?

Comment: One codebase running running at two organisations with different infrastructures.

Comment: impressive. I wonder if you could rewrite part of the Gemfile as part of one of the steps after deploy?

Comment: I think the major problem is the Gemfile.lock . AFAIK you need to install all the gems on your local machine before deploying with Capistrano in order to generate the Gemfile.lock?